# What is the difference between using an adverb + verb vs adjective + noun?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Here are two sentences:

> 1. He deeply appreciated art.
> 2. He had a deep appreciation of art.

What are the differences between the two sentences — more specifically, between "*deeply appreciate*" and "*had a deep appreciation*"?  Does one give more emphasis than the other? Or are the differences too small and subtle to fuss over?

Comment: i don't see any difference in the import of the two sentences.

Comment: The first one is correct and the second is nearly correct as an alternative. We do _not_ have an appreciation _for_ something but an appreciation _of_ something. We can have love or affection _for_ something (without an indefinite article) and _a_ love _of_ something but the use of an article turns the emotion into a noun and that takes _of_ not _for_. Your second example should be "He had a deep appreciation of art" or "He had deep appreciation for art" although the last one is much less common.

Comment: @BoldBen I dunno, *appreciation for* seems to be getting more and more common all the time: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=an+appreciation+for%2Can+appreciation+of&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Can%20appreciation%20for%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Can%20appreciation%20of%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 1):

He deeply appreciated art.
He had a deep appreciation of art.
What are the differences between the two sentences — more specifically, between "deeply appreciate" and "had a deep appreciation"? Does one give more emphasis than the other? Or are the differences too small and subtle to fuss over?

These sentences indicate the same meaning. I wouldn’t worry about it, they both sound correct! :)